# What to do when a question is marked as duplicate, but is linked incorrect?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30070121/4516316) is marked as duplicate, and

> [This question already has an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27006489/comparing-arrays-of-different-sizes-without-any-loop): Comparing arrays of
>   different sizes without any loop 2 answers

But when I follow [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27006489/comparing-arrays-of-different-sizes-without-any-loop), I notice that the subject is the same, but the languages are not (java vs matlab). So the question isn't a duplicate of *that* question. Maybe this was linked incorrectly?

What can I do to report this?

Comment: I've got the popcorn out waiting for this to be marked as a duplicate. :)

Comment: @TechnikEmpire I know :-) but since there is no other way to report this...

Comment: No one else was doing it, so I did. :) It's so funny because even the referenced duplicate is a duplicate of a duplicate. So your duplicate question led you to ask a duplicate question which is answered by a duplicate to a duplicate. At least in the SE universe, it's duplicates all the way down.

Comment: Yeah... except that I didn't ask the question, so I can't edit it... I'll flag it and say it needs the attention of a moderator...

Comment: @TomJonckheere I wasn't being rude, I was jabbing at how our site(s) are littered with duplicates. As you can see on the linked duplicate, even a long-time moderator (and I believe employee?) answered the duplicate instead of discovering it was a duplicate and marking it as so. I also mean "your" just in a sense that you brought it up. I fully agree with you, it's erroneously marked duplicate.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire, also didn't mean to come over rude! So no hard feelings!